# Retrieve annotations from XML schema using Xerces XML schema API?

Tags: java, xsd, xerces

I'm using the Xerces implementation of the XML schema API to query an existing XML schema for annotations. For example:

```
    String xml =
            "<xs:schema xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>" +
            "  <xs:annotation>" +
            "    <xs:documentation>test</xs:documentation>" +
            "  </xs:annotation>" +
            "</xs:schema>";

    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema s = sf.newSchema(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes())));

    XMLGrammarPool gp = ((XSGrammarPoolContainer) s).getGrammarPool();
    Grammar[] gs = gp.retrieveInitialGrammarSet(XMLGrammarDescription.XML_SCHEMA);
    System.out.println(((XSGrammar) gs[0]).toXSModel().getAnnotations());
```

This gives me the list of annotations as expected:

```
[com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XSAnnotationImpl@23d1ab]
```

When looking at the contents of the annotation (call getAnnotationString() on the annotation in the list), I get:

```
<xs:annotation xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
<xs:documentation>test</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
```

But when using a DOMSource instead of a StreamSource when creating the Schema object like this:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document d = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
    Schema s = sf.newSchema(new DOMSource(d));
```

The resulting grammar object doesn't seem to contain any annotations. getAnnotations() returns an empty list in this case.

Why do I get a different result when using a DOMSource instead of a StreamSource?